# Why inline-block is not working to align two divs inside of a parent container div horizontally side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML template like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
        border:green 2px solid;
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header {
        background-color : red;
        width:70%;
        height:80px;
        border:black 2px solid;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header1 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        border:green 2px solid;

    }
    #header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        border:green 2px solid;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
        <div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !!    </h1></div>            
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentHeader">
            <p>You Select ... We Serve </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>WebApp Version Numbered v1.0. All rights Reserved. </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I set the width to 50% for the divs having ids as `header1` and `header2` they tend not to occupy the entire space of the parent container div having id `header` and be aligned horizontally side by side. Why is it so ? 
Am I missing something here ? Please explain the basics as I am a newbie to HTML and CSS.

Comment: check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/pc4a5rr0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is remove `padding` from `#header`, then you give `2px` border to both `#header1` and `#header2` Remove it `border: 2px solid green;`

And another thing is `display:inline-block` takes white-space in the html. So, remove whitespace between both div `#header1` and `#header2`.

Like: `<div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div><div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !!    </h1></div>`

Here also i give `vertical-align:top` to make then vertically top.

```css
*{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
        border:green 2px solid;
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header {
        background-color : red;
        width:70%;
        height:80px;
        border:black 2px solid;
    }
    #header1 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    #header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div><div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !!    </h1></div>            
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentHeader">
            <p>You Select ... We Serve </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>WebApp Version Numbered v1.0. All rights Reserved. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/odu9aorz/1/)

Comment: P.S. vertical-align:middle is not vertically aligning the two divs inside of the container div ? Why is it so? Please explain.

Comment: You should use `line-height: 80px;` for that.

Answer (score 3):

try this ..

```
#header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  border: black 2px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

U may be responsive properly .

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there are two problems:

The first one, you declare `50% + 4px` border for each, in total these the header boxes has `width > 100%` (parent) and they can't be side by side.

The second one, if you remove border, between them is a space (caused by line break in your code).

You can remove white chars between them

```
<div id=header1>content</div><div id=header2>content></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4pybf6x/

or use `float` instead of `inline-block`.

When you use `float: left` for both elements, don't forget to clear after, eg. adding `overflow: hidden` to `#header`.

```
#header {overflow: hidden}
#header1, #header2 {float: left; border: 0; width: 50%;} /* no display: inline-block needed */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4pybf6x/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
#header1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
    border:green 2px solid;
    float: left;}
    #header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:49%;
        border:green 2px solid;float: right    }
```

The width should be 49% as the border is also set to 2 px so 50% will arrange the div one below the another, and any value less than 50% will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/pc4a5rr0/4/)

```
*{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
        border:green 2px solid;
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header {
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color : red;
        width:75%;
        height:80px;
        border:black 2px solid;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header1 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:35%;
        border:green 2px solid;
        background: red;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    #header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        border:green 2px solid;
        background: red;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Comment: P.S. vertical-align:middle is not vertically aligning the two divs inside of the container div ? Why is it so? Please explain.

Comment: I just aligned it in middle and it worked. I updated the fiddle, you can check.